# LINQ MAX giving exception when empty result

Tags: c#, linq

Currently the following statement is giving error. It is working if the result is returned but will produce this exception when no result is available

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified method
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]
>   Max[<>f__AnonymousType57`3,Nullable`1](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType57`3
>   ..., System.Func`2[<>f__AnonymousType57`3 ...
>   ,System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]])' on the type
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities
>   store expression because no overload matches the passed arguments.'

From what I gather, it is trying to do emulate this SQL which select user with the least number of tickets

```
select top 1  * from (
    select user_id, max(first_name) first_name, max(last_name) last_name, 
        max(CONVERT(int,retired)) retired, count(user_id) ticket_count 
    from table1 tb1  group by user_id) tb2 
order by tb2.ticket_count asc
```

```
var agentticketcountlist = (from tb1 in db.TABLE1 
   where tb1.GRP_ID == _ID  
   group new { tb1 } by tb1.USER_ID into g
   let first = g.FirstOrDefault()
select new
{
   USER_ID = g.Key ,
    FIRST_NAME = g.Max(x => x.tb1.FIRST_NAME),
    LAST_NAME = g.Max(x => x.tb1.LAST_NAME),
    RETIRED = g.Max(x =>x.tb1.RETIRED)  ,
    TICKET_COUNT = g.Count()
}).OrderBy(n => n.TICKET_COUNT).ToList();

if (agentticketcountlist.Count() > 0)
...
```

Edit

i have simplified the statement to 1 table as it was joining a few tables.

but here is some sample data according to the sample i gave (dont go table normalisation on me :) )

SQL Table Datatype. Note that bit becomes bool? in EF
USER_ID (nvarchar)
FIRST_NAME (nvarchar)
LAST_NAME (nvarchar)
RETIRED (bit)

123, jane, doe, 0
123, jane, doe, 0
234, john, doe, 1

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give any sample data, so it is not clear what your data looks like. From error message, as I understand Retired is a boolean and thus what you are really after is that is true or false:

```
var agentticketcountlist = (from tb1 in db.TABLE1 
   where tb1.GRP_ID == _ID  
   group tb1 by tb1.USER_ID into g
select new
{
    USER_ID = g.Key ,
    FIRST_NAME = g.Max(x => x.tb1.FIRST_NAME),
    LAST_NAME = g.Max(x => x.tb1.LAST_NAME),
    RETIRED = g.Any(x =>x.tb1.RETIRED),
    TICKET_COUNT = g.Count()
}).OrderBy(n => n.TICKET_COUNT).ToList();
```

EDIT:

```
var agentticketcountlist = (from tb1 in db.TABLE1 
   where tb1.GRP_ID == _ID  
   group tb1 by tb1.USER_ID into g
select new
{
    USER_ID = g.Key ,
    FIRST_NAME = g.Max(x => x.FIRST_NAME),
    LAST_NAME = g.Max(x => x.LAST_NAME),
    RETIRED = g.Any(x =>x.RETIRED),
    TICKET_COUNT = g.Count()
}).OrderBy(n => n.TICKET_COUNT).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. have edited to include the sample data and table defination

Comment: @Airwind, the code I gave already matches the case. Oops I just noticed a flaw in your original code, editing it now.

Answer (score 0):

Before max value, you need to add its default value in case there is no result found from the query:

`.DefaultIfEmpty(0)` or `.Max(x => x.value as int?) ?? 0` or `DefaultIfEmpty()`